# Laravel Intervention Image: Save image directly from dropbox url

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I was trying to store image from dropbox url to my local folder with laravel Intervention , but with it i am getting errors after error.

Can anyone please tell me how can i do so ?

My code is this

```
 $path = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwswp91fiz0m1wd/1200px-Good_Food_Display_-_NCI_Visuals_Online.jpg?dl=0';
        $filename = explode('?',basename($path))[0];
        Image::make($path)->save('images/'.$filename);
```

The error i am getting for this is

```
Unable to init from given binary data.
```

So i tried the solution from of of stackoverflow post

```
$path = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwswp91fiz0m1wd/1200px-Good_Food_Display_-_NCI_Visuals_Online.jpg?dl=0';

        $filename = explode('?',basename($path))[0];
        $path = base64_decode($path);
        Image::make($path)->save('images/'.$filename);
```

But that gave me another error.
I tried looking on goggle but i didn't find any solid answer that works for my case
Can anyone please help me on this how to download image from dropbox url and save to loacal storage ? Or do i have to add dropbox api or something??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropbox link that you used `https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwswp91fiz0m1wd/1200px-Good_Food_Display_-_NCI_Visuals_Online.jpg?dl=0` is a image preview page, which is not a valid image content. You can use force download mode to fetch the image content from dropbox, by editing the query parameter from `?dl=0` to `?raw=1`.

```
$path = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwswp91fiz0m1wd/1200px-Good_Food_Display_-_NCI_Visuals_Online.jpg?raw=1';
Image::make($path)->save('images/'.$filename);
```

See also: [Force a file or folder to download, or to render on dropbox.com](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/force-download)